# Give a function for the position of an object attached to a spring over time

Tags: classical-mechanics, spring, elasticity

Say we compress an object with mass $m$ up against a horizontal spring (on a frictionless surface) with stiffness constant $k$ such that the spring is $x$ meters away from being "relaxed." Hook's Law defines the force of the spring at that point to be $F_s=kx$.

I know that the object will oscillate after being released.  I want to solve for $x$ as a function of time, $t$, so that I can graph this, but I can't find a way to insert time into the equation.

Comment: Hint: $F=ma=m\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of motion is

$$\begin{align}M\cdot a &= F\\m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}&=-kx\end{align}$$

Putting $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, the solution for this is

$$x = A\cos(\omega t + \phi)$$

You find $A$, the amplitude, and $\phi$, the phase, by solving for the boundary conditions. For example if the initial displacement is $x_0$ and the object is released from rest, then $A=x_0$ and $\phi = 0$.